# My bot is running in the terminal, but wont produce an output on Discord- js

Tags: node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I'm pretty new so excuse my lack of technical terms. The bot is running (token is correct) and has no errors in the terminal, but I am not getting a reply to my message in Discord.

I was getting `BOT NOT DEFINED` error, but I moved `client.login(TOKEN)` to the last line of the code, and it went away.   I am following the tutorial code pretty closely, so I am not sure why I am getting the error.

Using node v16.9.1

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] })


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`It's welcome time`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'Hi') {
    msg.reply('Welcome wallet warrior!');
    msg.channel.send('Welcome wallet warrior!');

  }
  else {
    msg.channel.send('Hi, please introduce yourself')
  };

});
const TOKEN = '(ERASED MY TOKEN)';
console.log(TOKEN)
client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: You `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES` added into your intent, otherwise your bot is unable to see guild messages

Comment: @Elitezen okay so i added GUILD_MESSAGES.

and now I am getting [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'

Comment: I found this link for a fix but after adding intents it still throws the same 'BITFIELD_INVALID' errors 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68796168/i-am-having-this-throw-new-rangeerrorbitfield-invalid-bit-error-and-i

Comment: That's a different issue than the one in this question, consider making a new post